# how to stop kendo grid refresh when adding a new row?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid that I am adding a new row to on a button click event, the problem I am having is adding a new row without the grid being refreshed.

my click event is

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnAddNewArea', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    StopDetailCollapse("#TabEditor");
    AddNewRowToGrid(".eagClass");
});
```

and my add row function is

```
function AddNewRowToGrid(gridID) {
    var grid = $(gridID).data("kendoGrid");
    //grid.AddRow();
    grid.dataSource.insert(
        0,
        {
            AreaID: -1,
            AreaName: "New Area",
            Catalog: 0
        });
}
```

I thought the e.preventDefault would have stopped it but I am wrong.

So, in short, how do you stop the grid from refreshing when adding a new row?

Comment: I'm afraid this is an internal behaviour and cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the grid's [addRow](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/addrow) method, rather than manipulate it's datasource directly (note: it is case sensitive). It shouldn't refresh it's contents when you do it that way (it looks like you tried that, but possibly got the casing wrong?)

Comment: `addRow` is not made for that purpose.

Comment: @chris has "a grid that I am adding a new row to", which is exactly what the grid's `addRow` method does. From the API Reference I linked: _Adds an empty data item to the grid. In "incell" and "inline" editing mode a table row will be appended. Popup window will be displayed in "popup" editing mode._ I see now I might have misunderstood the problem of the refresh (I took that to mean his code was refreshing the datasource)

Comment: *"Adds an empty data item to the grid"* the user wants do add a prefilled row with data(check the code in the question), and not an empty row.

Comment: Maybe he does want a prefilled row, but that's not the question that was asked: "how to stop kendo grid refresh" ... "the problem I am having is adding a new row without the grid being refreshed" ... "in short, how do you stop the grid from refreshing". The way to provide a prefilled row is to populate the `defaultValue` properties in the grid datasource schema / model / fields definition. Calling `addRow` in that scenario will pass along a pre-populated model object to the grid.